# Disappearing users and the consequences

Tags: discussion, badges, deleted-users

I noticed that I lost 20 points recently and when I went to look, the screen read something to the effect of "user removed". I am just wondering what happens if a person earns a badge based on material submitted for a question (or answer) which is later removed. If I get a badge for choosing a best answer and then that user (and his answer) is removed, do I lose the badge? I think there was a similar question in the box on the right but as I went to click on it, it disappeared.

Comment: related? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17077/1601 heh heh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Once you earn a badge, it's your to keep, except for [the tag badges](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/badges?tab=tags). ([Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17854); see there for further details.)

Comment: thank you. (a character limit makes simple politeness tough in a comment)

Comment: but you do lose the rep when a user leaves/is removed?

Comment: @vram, yes, I believe so.